# Could not mount NetApp volume through NFS: rpcinfo: RPC: Timed out

Tags: linux, nfs, onc-rpc

I am trying to mount one of NFS volume exported from NetApp storage but getting below error.

10.242.12.24 is my NFS server. I am trying to mount on Suse 11.4 which is my NFS
client.

```
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'hard,addr=10.242.12.24'    
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6    
mount.nfs: trying 10.242.12.24 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049    
mount.nfs: portmap query retrying: RPC: Timed out    
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=17    
mount.nfs: trying 10.242.12.24 prog 100003 vers 3 prot UDP port 2049    
mount.nfs: portmap query failed: RPC: Timed out    
mount.nfs: mount to NFS server '10.242.12.24:/vol/v_fs0028' failed: timed out, giving up
```

If run the below command, I get an error:

```
iza0560:/tmp # rpcinfo -t 10.242.12.24 nfs    
rpcinfo: RPC: Timed out   
program 100003 version 0 is not available

iza0560:/tmp # rpcinfo -u 10.242.12.24 nfs    
rpcinfo: RPC: Timed out    
program 100003 version 0 is not available

iza0560:/tmp #

iza0560:/tmp # rpcinfo -p 10.242.12.24    
   program vers proto   port  service    
    100011    1   udp   4049  rquotad    
    100024    1   tcp   4047  status    
    100024    1   udp   4047  status    
    100021    4   tcp   4045  nlockmgr    
    100021    3   tcp   4045  nlockmgr    
    100021    1   tcp   4045  nlockmgr    
    100021    4   udp   4045  nlockmgr    
    100021    3   udp   4045  nlockmgr    
    100021    1   udp   4045  nlockmgr    
    100005    3   tcp   4046  mountd    
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs    
    100005    2   tcp   4046  mountd    
    100005    1   tcp   4046  mountd    
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs    
    100005    3   udp   4046  mountd    
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs    
    100005    2   udp   4046  mountd    
    100005    1   udp   4046  mountd    
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs    
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper    
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
```

Telnet over port 111, 2049 and others of NFS server are working.

Comment: Perhaps the Netapp is only serving out NFSv4?

Comment: Does `showmount -e <nfsserver>` work?  If not (and other clients are working), I'd probably do a packet capture for the showmount and see if anything obvious appears.

Comment: A timeout is a hint that a machine is filtering your traffic. Check your client and server iptables rules. Retest after flushing those rules if you can. BTW, you successfully connected to the `nfsd` port, but did you try to connect to the `mountd` port?

Comment: NetApp is using version 2 and 3 . It is clear from above output of rpcinfo -p netappip command. yes showmount -e netappip works fine. NFS client is suse is having no iptables rules and nfs server is netapp so there is iptables on netapp side.Yes i am able to connect on mountd successfully.

Comment: Common issues w/ NFS & NetApp - https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1001083.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may have failed to allow your host to connect in the NFS Export Policy on your NetApp. [Check your export rule to ensure the IP or subnet of your host are allowed to connect to that filer's NFS export.](https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1287610/html/GUID-FC041987-F793-427E-BB00-19D3DB1F30DA.html)

Comment: Export rules on the Netapp will cause `mount` to fail, usually with a nice permission error, but not timeouts.  The RPC errors point to at least some other source of trouble.

Comment: Export rules from netapp side are fine and if it is related to export rules it will give me permission deny error.

Comment: Then I guess the next step would be to check your firewall(s)

Comment: Hi James there is no firewall

Comment: Not even firewalld? Are is the filer and server on the same subnet?