# Unable to NFS mount "Program not registered error"

Tags: linux, nfs

I'm trying to `mount` an NFS volume with no success. I'm running Linux 7.3 as a VM. I don't see any error messages in `/var/log/messages`. These are the steps I've taken so far:

*showmount*

```
[root@backup ~]# showmount -e 192.168.1.212
clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered
```

*systemd NFS status*

```
[root@backup ~]# systemctl status nfs
â nfs-server.service - NFS server and services
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2018-08-10 13:38:11 MDT; 26min ago
  Process: 961 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.nfsd $RPCNFSDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 939 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /bin/kill -HUP `cat /run/gssproxy.pid` (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 937 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/exportfs -r (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 961 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nfs-server.service


Aug 10 13:38:11 backup systemd[1]: Starting NFS server and services...
Aug 10 13:38:11 backup systemd[1]: Started NFS server and services.
```

*nfslock*

```
[root@backup ~]# systemctl status nfslock
â rpc-statd.service - NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking.
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpc-statd.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-08-10 13:38:11 MDT; 27min ago
  Process: 926 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rpc.statd $STATDARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 933 (rpc.statd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rpc-statd.service
           ââ933 /usr/sbin/rpc.statd


Aug 10 13:38:11 backup systemd[1]: Starting NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking....
Aug 10 13:38:11 backup rpc.statd[933]: Version 1.3.0 starting
Aug 10 13:38:11 backup rpc.statd[933]: Flags: TI-RPC
Aug 10 13:38:11 backup systemd[1]: Started NFS status monitor for NFSv2/3 locking..
```

*systemd rpcbind status*

```
[root@backup ~]# systemctl status rpcbind
â rpcbind.service - RPC bind service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rpcbind.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-08-10 13:38:10 MDT; 28min ago
  Process: 685 ExecStart=/sbin/rpcbind -w $RPCBIND_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 688 (rpcbind)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rpcbind.service
           ââ688 /sbin/rpcbind -w

Aug 10 13:38:10 backup systemd[1]: Starting RPC bind service...
Aug 10 13:38:10 backup systemd[1]: Started RPC bind service.
```

*rpcinfo*

```
[root@backup ~]# rpcinfo -p 192.168.1.212 | cut -c30- | sort -u    
portmapper
service
ypbind
```

I don't understand why the `rpcinfo` is missing NFS? Are there any other commands I can try to troubleshoot this?

Comment: My first thought is firewall. Is it blocking? https://www.howtoforge.com/nfs-server-and-client-on-centos-7

Comment: That was my first thought as well. However I disable the firewall.

Comment: I setup NFS locally on CentOS 7.x using this guide and it works fine - https://www.howtoforge.com/nfs-server-and-client-on-centos-7

Comment: This seems possible related - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394781/could-not-mount-netapp-volume-through-nfs-rpcinfo-rpc-timed-out/394825.

Comment: This issue seems to be w/ the NetApp - https://kb.netapp.com/app/answers/answer_view/a_id/1001083.

Comment: In my case, I was using the `v3` flag when my server was on v4. After removing that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The message "Program not registered" indicates a problem on the server, at least I assume that 192.168.1.212 is your server as it is not necessary to add an address to showmount to get information about the local host.

So you should make sure that the NFS server is running on the server. Start with

```
rpcinfo 192.168.1.212
```

And if possible verify that the processes are running on the server.

Comment: The server in may case is a NetApp. I've created the volumes, and policies, but I can double check to make sure I didn't miss a step.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the nfs-mountd service is running:

```
systemctl status nfs-mountd
```

restart nfs-server service as needed